# How can I locate and enter text in the search box on Lidl's website using Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How do I locate and enter text into this search box on the Lidl website, I'm up to the point where the web page loads and the search area comes up. The locator for the box is what I need.

https://www.lidl.co.uk/about-us/store-finder-opening-hours#

I am using selenium to find the search box that comes up after selecting store finder to enter a postcode and ultimately extract the postcodes of the stores displayed

Thank you

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using python @TheCoder

Comment: I don't find a search box on the [webpage](https://www.lidl.co.uk/about-us/store-finder-opening-hours#) really. What are the manual steps to pullout the search box?

Comment: You click on the locate store button and a window opens on the RHS of the screen

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do that:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions, Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
url = "https://www.lidl.co.uk/about-us/store-finder-opening-hours#"
driver.get(url)

# wait for element to get located to click the "ACCEPT" cookies button
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.cookie-alert-extended-button"))).click()
# wait for element to get located to click the "STORE SEARCH" button
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.nuc-m-button.nuc-a-button"))).click()
# wait for element to get located to Enter post code or city
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[placeholder="Enter post code or city"]'))).send_keys('London')

time.sleep(10)
```

Few things to note:

1. First, as we hit the URL, a cookie pops up that we can accept to continue. So we wait for this pop-up and click on the `ACCEPT` button.
2. Next, we wait for the `STORE SEARCH` button to get located and then click.
3. It loads a side search box where we can enter the city or the postcode to search. So we wait for this to get loaded/located in order to enter the query. we can use `send_keys()` method to enter/input either the city name or the postcode.

for example, as we enter the city name/postcode (London), a dropdown list appears with available stores in that region, you can choose accordingly and proceed further.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you so much! How did you locate the CSS id here? Would you always recommend using CSS as opposed to XPATH?

Comment: to locate the SELECTOR, you can simply inspect the page and hover over to the desired element you're looking for, it'll show you the CSS selector and it's up to you to choose between XPATH and CSS selector. I use both